# Blazor WebAssembly Debug fails

Tags: debugging, blazor, webassembly

Won't set breakpoint in Debug mode.  Referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-code  but it still doesn't work.

Create a new HOSTED WebAssembly application in Visual Studio (2019).
Run it by pressing F5 (debug)

Go to the Counter.razor and set a break point on the currentCount++ line.

IT SHOULD Set a breakpoint but on my PC it's an empty circle (red border white inside).
Tried it in VSCode and it didn't work there either.

Any clue on what's happening?  I have the latest VS 2019.  Don't know where else to look.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I find if I set the breakpoint before I press f5 it works better. If you are doing this you might try cleaning and rebuilding the solution.

Comment: :-)  Thanks .. I tried that, but I'm still having trouble.  I tried it on my laptop and it still fails.  I appreciate your help though.  Chuck (Yogi)